# Skin Detection Opencv-Temperature Parameter

Tags: opencv, image-processing, skin

I was working on the skin detection in OpenCV.I am using YCrCb color range for detection.It was working fine for most of the image but in one case it was not working.
[Image Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyPWD.jpg)

So I tried to do some adjustment in the images because you can see that skin color range is not even visible,so I edited the pic in Windows Photos Application in Window 8.In that software I changed "color->Temperature" setting and set the value to 80 or something.
The output image was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtikA.jpg).

Now the Skin detection works perfectly fine.Can anyone explain me the temperature parameter used in Photos app and what it exactly does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color temperature is part of the White Balance of an image.
Basically, at different lighting conditions the same white color looks different.
This process "White Balance" should compensate for that.

Have a look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance

http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/white-balance.htm

Comment: i was able to change the temperature of image using white balance but I dont want to apply white balance correction for all the image,it should apply to only images which are more cold.So how do I check this condition?

Comment: This will require analysis of the colors in the image. Something like the relation between the warm and cold shades. You actually want to tale whether the White Balance is wrong and if it is wrong, is it "Too Cold". I think it is easier just to correct it. Naive easy step would be equalize the histogram of each color.

Comment: Just for info as per New opencv 3.0,they have release WhiteBalance API
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/xphoto/doc/whitebalance.html